# Old Style Oracle Joins in Kafka

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka

Please can someone help with a Kafka question? For Kafka querying an Oracle database is there a way to use the old (+) style joins in the connectors rather than the newer 'right, left join' style please? We have a mass of old queries we would like to re-use. Something in json maybe like an XML CData that avoids parsing and throws the query straight at the database. Thanks in Advance, Dave

Comment: Hi @Mrtea, can you clarify `For Kafka quering an Oracle database`? Are you using a particular connector?

Comment: Thanks Robin, It's the JDBC Connector for Confluent Platform. https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/index.html